# Order of global truncation error

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, interpolation

I was reading something,here is something I stuck with the following integral is approximated using numerical methods
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s(t)}  v\,dx\ = \int_{0}^{kh}  v\,dx\ + \int_{kh}^{s(t)}  v\,dx\ 
\end{align}
where  $$ k=\lfloor s(t)/h \rfloor,$$ 
this integral is approximated using composite trapezoidal and interpolation,  the first integral on the R.H.S. is solved using composite trapezoidal rule and the second is solved using interpolation.
Here is the approximation of second one
\begin{align}
\int_{kh}^{s(t)}  v\,dx\ = \left (\delta-\frac{\delta^2 }{2h}\right)v_k ~~+ ~~ \left(\frac{\delta^2 }{2h}\right)v_{k+1}
\end{align}
$$ \delta = s(t)-kh $$
I have two doubts here, the first one is, I did not get this approximation using interpolation and second doubt is that this complete approximation  is given with global truncation error of $O(h^2),~~$ this is also not clear to me. I know composite trapezoidal rule has truncation error of order $O(h^2)$ but for the interpolation part it is not clear to me.
Please help me out with this and please correct me if I have said anything wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not want the floor of $s(t)/h $ for $k$? So that $kh\le s(t)\le(k+1)h$? What exactly is computed? Is the table of approximations for $V_k=\int_0^{kh}v\,dt$ pre-computed so that a cubic interpolation using $(v_k, V_k), (v_{k+1},V_{k+1})$ is performed for intermediate values?

Comment: Thanks. I have made changes. we are approximating that integral using numerical methods. No we are using composite trapezoidal rule to approximate that integral(0 to $ kh $). I don't know much about interpolation, whether its cubic interpolation or something else, that is what I want to know. Can you please help me out with this which interpolation is this one.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a part of a procedure where the values $v_k$ are some fixed, pre-computed table of function values. Essentially you integrate the piecewise linear approximation of $v$. For that you split the input $s(t)=kh+δ$. On each interval you approximate
$$
v(s)\approx v_j+\frac{s-jh}{h}(v_{j+1}-v_j)\text{ for } jh\le s<(j+1)h
$$
For the full intervals the integal results in the trapezoidal formula $\frac h2(v_j+v_{j+1})$, for the last partial interval
$$
\int_{kh}^{kh+δ}v_k+\frac{s-kh}{h}(v_{k+1}-v_k)ds=\Bigl[sv_k+\frac{(s-kh)^2}{2h}(v_{k+1}-v_k)\Bigr]_{kh}^{kh+δ}v_k=δv_k+\frac{δ^2}{2h}(v_{j+1}-v_j)
$$
which is your last interpolation formula.

The distance of the piecewise linear interpolation to the original function is $O(h^2)$ if the function $v$ is smooth enough, thus in the integral the error is of the same size, more specifically $O(s(t)h^2)$.

Comment: My mistake $$ \delta = s(t)-kh $$, I have edited that..

Comment: Ya $ v_k $ are pre computed here

Comment: $$
v(s)\approx v_j+\frac{s-jh}{h}(v_{j+1}-v_j)\text{ for } jh\le s<(j+1)h
$$ I did not get this step..

Comment: It is a linear function on $[jh,(j+1)h]$ that goes from $v_j$ to $v_{j+1}$. This is exactly what the linear interpolation should do.

Comment: Thank you so much.. My last doubt is why we have broken this integral into two parts and applied two different numerical methods. why not this integral was just approximated by one method either by interpolation or by trapezoidal. Please help me out with this one.